# Access key getting selected even we did not press 'Alt' key in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, access-keys

I have WPF application which is having tool bar. In tool bar I have some user controls as tools.

I have set access key to each control, it is working fine.

The issue is: If I click a user control(which is consist of Button and Label, I have set access key for Button) the given task is completed, but when I press any access key without pressing 'Alt' key then it is getting selected.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, this was a deliberate change by Microsoft. See Atanas Koralski's answer here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/14f6f49f-0027-471b-b68c-e7f6ba012012

> Menu and ToolBar mnemonics work without pressing Alt key. We decided
>   that we will have uniform behavior in all cases so access key work
>   without pressing Alt key.
>
> I understand that this is not in parity with Forms and we will
>   consider this issue and change the behavior in the next version.
>
> For now as a workaround you can register a class handler for all
>   AccessKeyPressed events and handle the event if Alt key is not
>   pressed.
>
> ```
> EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(UIElement),
> AccessKeyManager.AccessKeyPressedEvent,
> new AccessKeyPressedEventHandler(OnAccessKeyPressed));
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> private static void OnAccessKeyPressed(object sender, AccessKeyPressedEventArgs e)
> {
>     if (!e.Handled && e.Scope == null && (e.Target == null || e.Target == label))
>     {
>         // If Alt key is not pressed - handle the event
>         if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Alt) != ModifierKeys.Alt)
>         {
>             e.Target = null;
>             e.Handled = true;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Also see mfc2wpf's reply:

> I've used the above and it works.  However, that prevented the default
>   action for Enter and ESC.  So I inserted the following at the top of
>   the method.
>
> ```
> if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Enter) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Escape)) return;
> ```

Access keys include <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd>, which are the default keys for `Button`s which have `IsDefault = true` or `IsCancel = true`. If you don't want to require <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> for those buttons, you would need to add the special condition to the handler.

Answer (score 5):

As of .Net 4.5 you can configure this behavior with the [CoreCompatibilityPreferences.IsAltKeyRequiredInAccessKeyDefaultScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.corecompatibilitypreferences.isaltkeyrequiredinaccesskeydefaultscope(v=vs.110).aspx) property.  To change the access key behavior so that they will only fire when Alt is pressed set it to true.

```
CoreCompatibilityPreferences.IsAltKeyRequiredInAccessKeyDefaultScope = true;
```

As the documentation states this must early in the app.  Setting it will throw an exception after it has been read.

Comment: I have to note that setting IsAltKeyRequiredInAccessKeyDefaultScope to true also disables ENTER and ESC for buttons marked with IsDefault and IsCancel when ALT is not pressed.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in other answers, setting `IsAltKeyRequiredInAccessKeyDefaultScope` avoids invoking actions for access keys without pressing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. However, this can also have the effect of disabling the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key (for invoking the default action) and <kbd>Esc</kbd> key (for invoking the Cancel action).

Using the suggested workaround instead, and testing for `Key.Enter` and `Key.Escape`, can circumvent this problem. However, you might then find that menu items cannot be selected by their access key without pressing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, which could be a problem if a button in scope uses the same access key.

An alternative could then be to handle the access key event by checking whether a potentially invokable `AccessText` control is within a `MenuItem` or not, something along these lines:

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(
  typeof(UIElement),
  AccessKeyManager.AccessKeyPressedEvent,
  new AccessKeyPressedEventHandler(OnAccessKeyPressed));
```

...

```
static void OnAccessKeyPressed(object accessKeyTarget, AccessKeyPressedEventArgs e)
{
  if (!e.Handled && e.Scope == null &&
    (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Alt) != ModifierKeys.Alt &&
    !ShouldElementHandleAccessKeysWhenAltIsNotPressed(accessKeyTarget as UIElement))
  {
    e.Target = null;
    e.Handled = true;
  }
}

static bool ShouldElementHandleAccessKeysWhenAltIsNotPressed(UIElement element)
{
  if (element == null) return false;
  var accessText = element as AccessText;
  if (accessText != null && !IsDecendantOfMenuItem(accessText)) return false;
  return true;
}

static bool IsDecendantOfMenuItem(DependencyObject element)
{
  for (; element != null; element = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element))
    if (element is MenuItem) return true;
  return false;
}
```